# How to execute the following bash statement in npm script?

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I know there are many ways to do this, but I'm using the 'npm scripts' as my build tool. I'm stuck on this simple `echo` statement that will `source` my .bash_plugin into the .bash_profile:

```
  "scripts": {
    "info": "echo 'npm as a build tool'",
    "installBashPlugin": "echo 'source ~/.bash_plugins/.my_plugin' >> '~/.bash_profile'"
```

What am I doing wrong here? I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the buildtool@1.0.0 bash script 'echo 'source ~/.bash_plugins/.my_plugin' >> '~/.bash_profile''.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh sh*t I got this.

```
"scripts": {
    "info": "echo 'npm as a build tool'",
    "installBashPlugin": "echo 'source ~/.bash_plugins/.my_plugin' >> ~/.bash_profile"
```

Those single quotes around the target file: `.bash_profile` is where it errored out. Thanks.

Comment: `~` only gets expanded to the home directory path when it's left unquoted. So `~/'.bash_profile'` would work, but `'~/.bash_profile'` won't.